# how to subtract 5 days from all of my dates column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a column of different dates and there is data in it & I want to update my table such that It'll update the column to 5 days earlier .

Comment: [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve,

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `dateadd` function in sql server

```
update table 
set datecolumn=dateadd(dd,-5,datecolumn)
```

Comment: I want this to apply on all of my dates , and all the dates are different.

Comment: @ArUnGuPta if column belongs data type date or datetime  it will work for all records check once

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DATEADD()` with negative number to subtract day:

```
SELECT     
DATEADD(D, -5, YourColumn)    
FROM YourTable
```

**Be careful as the following code snippet will update ALL records**:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = DATEADD(D, -5, YourColumn)
```

Comment: I want this to apply on all of my dates , and all the dates are different.

Comment: There's no `WHERE` in this statement @ArUnGuPta, why do you think it would only apply to specific rows?

Comment: @ArUnGuPta yeah, the above code is to pudate all records in your table.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other solutions, if the column is datetime, you can use a simple - 5.

Example:

```
SELECT GETDATE(), GETDATE() - 5
```

Gives:

```
2019-04-09 15:01:26.973, 2019-04-04 15:01:26.973
```

Note that lots of people dislike this approach (if datatypes change, your code will break), however it is simple in its usage.